# Comparing files (the hard way)

Tags: java, file, comparator

I'm about to lose my mind on this one right here. I'd like to compare 4 files with each other.

They're split in 2 folders. So there is folder "A" with file 1-4
and there is folder "B" which is a copy of folder "A".

```
package Aufgabe2;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;



class FTWalker {
    FTWalkerTWO two;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new FTWalker().walk(args[0]);
    }

    void walk(String pathname) throws IOException {
        File[] files = new File(pathname).listFiles();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> liste2 = new ArrayList<String>();  
        int i = 0;


        if (files != null)
            for (File file: files)
                if (file.isDirectory())
                    walk(file.getCanonicalPath());
                else{
                    //      process(file.getCanonicalPath(), (int)file.length());
                    System.out.println(""+file.getName()); //gibt namen aus
                    list.add( (int) file.length());
                    liste2.add(file.getName());
                    i++;
                    duplikat(file,liste2);
                }
        //  sortiert(list);
    }

    void process(String name, int length) {
        System.out.printf("%-70s%9d%n", name, length);
    }

    void sortiert(List<Integer> a) {
        Collections.sort(a);
        for (int k = 0; k < a.size(); k++) {
            System.out.print(a.get(k) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

        Comparator<Integer> comparator = Collections.<Integer> reverseOrder();
        Collections.sort(a, comparator);

        for (int k = 0; k < a.size(); k++) {
            System.out.print(a.get(k) + " ");
        }
    }

    public void duplikat(File file,List<String> a ){//stand vorher List<String> liste2 drin
      //for(int i.)
        if(file.getName().equals(a.get(i)){
            System.out.println("Yo\n");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Sorry seems to be the hardest word\n");
        }

    }
}
```

The code above gets a folder at `args[0]`, walks through a directory which contains a couple of files and prints the whole path + the size of the file.

All I want is to see if the files name are equal or not!

I got z.txt in both folders - they are equal (name).  Then I changed one of them to z2.txt.  Now, I checked both have same name or not. But I don't get the correct result.

Comment: For your unerstanding:
One directory would be enough, too.
I just created a second directory because  I can't create a copy of the same file without changing the copys name (Windows).

z.txt -> copy -> paste-> z(2).txt

Comment: what is your exact requirement? You're saying that you want to compare file names only yet your code is not trying to compare filenames from different directories (comparing filenames in the same directory doesn't make sense since filenames must be unique at the same hierarchy level). Is this homework? If yes what's the original question as formulated by the teacher?

Comment: Assuming from the package name this is homework.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your replys.

What I want is to compare n files with each other.
Not the content but its names like "stackoverflow.txt"

I know that comparing files in the same directory doesn't make sense, so i created another directory with the same files.

In that excersise , I have to find a way to compare theese files...
I can do whatever I want... it just has to work.

I even had the idea to create another walker which walks through args[1] instead of args[0] to compare each file stored in args[0] + [1] to get the correct result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in that code.

A naive solution is to replace the [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) with a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and then add to it combination of file name and size.

Other solution is to create a object that will contain the file name and the size of it. That will override the implementation of [equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28%29) and [hashode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), and then use the [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to verify that a file of this type had  been found.

EDIT:

As you need only check the file name without any other restriction only thing that you could use a Set where you can store the file name. As you are walking through file system you just need to verify that such name is all ready in the set. In addition you need to store the amount of already found file names. To handle this you can used a HashMap where key is file name and Value is the amount.

```
if(nameMap.contains(file.getName()) {

  Integer index = nameMap.getValue(file.getName()) + 1;

   //rename file file.renameTo(new File(newPathWithIndex)));

} else {
  nameMap.put(file.getName(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In method duplikat, check with

```
a.contains(file.getName())
```

if the actual file's name is already in the list

Comment: Do not forget about the size;

Comment: @Vash - The idea was to test if a *filename* is a duplicate, not a *file*. Otherwise one would start comparing the `File` objects or calculating checksums on the file contents.

Comment: @Anreas_D, As we understand the file name with it extension, the it is impossible to have two files in the same hierarchy level.

Comment: @Vash - he's visiting subdirectories. And only looking at the file name (not the *full* name). So it shall give a `true` if he has two files with equal names in different subdirectories.

Comment: Well, I don't want to compare the path or the files 
I just want to see if they have the same filename..

So  I guess Andreas_D is right..

@Andreas_D I'll have a look at it and let you know about it ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Amir,

The 'list' and 'list2' are newly created on every walk() call.

Drag these variables out of the walk() method and make them static final. Once they are global and static same copy of list will be available for every walk() call.

Thanks,
Talha Ahmed Khan

Answer (score 0):

You can use my the following working code.

Example print out:

```
dene - Copy.txt filename duplicated at 
    f:\TEMP_USERS\test\2\dene - Copy.txt
    f:\TEMP_USERS\test\dene - Copy.txt
dene.txt filename duplicated at 
    f:\TEMP_USERS\test\1\dene.txt
    f:\TEMP_USERS\test\2\1\dene.txt
    f:\TEMP_USERS\test\2\dene.txt
    f:\TEMP_USERS\test\dene.txt
```

```
package info.kod;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class DuplicateFilenameFinder {

private Map<String, File>      uniqueFilenames;
private Map<String, List<File>> duplicateMap;

public DuplicateFilenameFinder() {
    uniqueFilenames = new HashMap<String, File>();
    duplicateMap = new HashMap<String, List<File>>();
}

private Map<String, List<File>> findDuplicateNames(String pathname) {
    File[] files = new File(pathname).listFiles();
    if (files == null) {
        return null;
    }

    for (final File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory() == true) {
            findDuplicateNames(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            checkAndAddDuplicate(file);
        }
    }

    return duplicateMap;
}

private void checkAndAddDuplicate(final File file) {
    final String filename = file.getName();
    if (uniqueFilenames.containsKey(filename) == false) {
        uniqueFilenames.put(filename, file);
        return;
    }
    List<File> dupFiles = duplicateMap.get(filename);
    if (dupFiles == null) {
        dupFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        dupFiles.add(uniqueFilenames.get(filename));
        dupFiles.add(file);

        duplicateMap.put(filename, dupFiles);
    } else {
        dupFiles.add(file);
    }
}

private void printOutDuplicatedFiles(final Map<String, List<File>> duplicateMap) {
    if ((duplicateMap == null) || (duplicateMap.size() < 1)) {
        System.out.println("No duplicate filename found");
        return;
    }
    final Set<Entry<String, List<File>>> entrySet = duplicateMap.entrySet();
    for (final Entry<String, List<File>> entry : entrySet) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " filename duplicated at ");
        final List<File> fileList = entry.getValue();
        for (File file : fileList) {
            System.out.println("    " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String pathname = args[0];
    final DuplicateFilenameFinder dupFinder = new DuplicateFilenameFinder();
    final Map<String, List<File>> duplicatedFiles = dupFinder.findDuplicateNames(pathname);
    dupFinder.printOutDuplicatedFiles(duplicatedFiles);
}

}
```